Android app keeps restarting after SIGFPE exception
I have an Android app whose logic is mostly in C++. W.r.t exception handling in C++, I'm using the Linux's signal handler mechanism to trap signals which get raised due to exceptions such as memory access violation, divide by zero etc.
// ExceptionHandlingCpp.h file

using SignalHandlerFunc = void (*) (int, siginfo_t *, void *);

struct tSignals {

    SignalHandlerFunc signalHandlerFunc;
    uint32_t          signal;
    [[maybe_unused]]
    uint8_t           reserved[4];
};

class ExceptionHandlingCpp {

public:

    static tSignals unixSignals[];

private:
    static uint8_t numOfRecursions;
    static thread_local uint8_t currentIteration;

    // Other private data members

public:

    static void RegisterSignals();
    static void HandleSignals(int pSignals, siginfo_t* pInfo, void* pContext);
    static void UnregisterSignal(int pSignal);
    static void CheckRecursiveExceptions(int pSignal);

    static void* DivisionByZero(void* pParms);

    // Other public member functions

};

// ExceptionHandlingCpp.cpp file

tSignals ExceptionHandlingCpp::unixSignals[] = {

        {HandleSignals, SIGFPE, {0}},
        {HandleSignals, SIGSEGV, {0}},
        {HandleSignals, SIGKILL, {0}},
};

uint8_t ExceptionHandlingCpp::numOfRecursions {5};
thread_local uint8_t ExceptionHandlingCpp::currentIteration {0};

void ExceptionHandlingCpp::RegisterSignals() {
    LOG("ExceptionHandlingCpp::RegisterSignals()");

    struct sigaction sa;

    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(unixSignals)/sizeof(tSignals); ++i) {

        sa.sa_sigaction = unixSignals[i].signalHandlerFunc;
        sigaction(unixSignals[i].signal, &sa, nullptr);
    }
}

void ExceptionHandlingCpp::HandleSignals(int pSignal, siginfo_t *pInfo, void *pContext) {
    LOG("ExceptionHandlingCpp::HandleSignals(int, signinfo_t*, void*)");

    LOG("signal = " + signalName(pSignal));

    // TODO: Handle the exception/signal.


    // Sets the default handler if the exception keeps repeating
    // more than 5 times. This is just to experiment what happens when
    // the default handler is set for the signal.
    CheckRecursiveExceptions(pSignal);

    // Record the exception count
    LOG("currentIteration = " + std::to_string(currentIteration));

    LOG("Returning from exception handler...");
}

void ExceptionHandlingCpp::UnregisterSignal(int pSignal) {

    LOG("ExceptionHandlingCpp::UnregisterSignal(int)");

    struct sigaction defaultAction {};
    defaultAction.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;

    if(sigaction(pSignal, &defaultAction, nullptr) == -1) {
        LOG("Error in resetting action for " + signalName(pSignal));
    } else {
        LOG("Successfully reset " + signalName(pSignal) + "'s action to default!");
    }
}

void ExceptionHandlingCpp::CheckRecursiveExceptions(int pSignal) {

    LOG("ExceptionHandlingCpp::CheckRecursiveExceptions()");

    currentIteration++;

    if(currentIteration > numOfRecursions) {
        // After repeating for said times, update the action for the signal to default and do nothing
        UnregisterSignal(pSignal);
    } else {
        LOG("Number of recursions so far = " + std::to_string(currentIteration));
    }
}

void* ExceptionHandlingCpp::DivisionByZero ([[maybe_unused]] void* pParms)
{
    LOG("ExceptionHandlingCpp::DivisionByZero()");

    int num1;
    int num2;
    int result;

    num1 = 5;
    num2 = 0;

    LOG("Raising exception...");

    result = num1 / num2;

    LOG("Returning from DivisionByZero() method");

    return nullptr;
}


std::string ExceptionHandlingCpp::signalName(int pSignal)
{
    switch(pSignal) {
        case SIGSEGV:
            return "SIGSEGV";
        case SIGFPE:
            return "SIGFPE";
        case SIGKILL:
            return "SIGKILL";
        default:
            return "Undefined signal!";
    }
}


In Activity.onCreate, I invoke the C++ function with a mangled name, Java_sample_experiments_androidexceptionhandling_KotlinExceptions_testExceptionHandlerFromCppregister handlers for some signals (SIGSEGV, SIGFPE and SIGKILL), and simulate a divide by zero exception by invoking ExceptionHandlingCpp::DivisionByZero method.
HandleSignals is my signal handler. When you simply return from the signal handler, the control goes back to the instruction that raised the signal, which then again invokes the signal handler. The only way out of this loop is to set the default handler for the signal.     I'm setting the default handler in UnregisterSignal method, which is invoked from the signal handler after 5 iterations.
The logcat has the following logs:
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (6199) for package sample.experiments.androidexceptionhandling ----------------------------
(2 | 6199) MainApplication.onCreate()
(6199) JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM*, void*)
(6199) Initializing JavaVM...
(2 | 6199) MainActivity.onCreate(Bundle?)
(6199) Java_sample_experiments_androidexceptionhandling_KotlinExceptions_testExceptionHandlerFromCpp(JNIEnv *, jobject)
(6199) ExceptionHandlingCpp::RegisterSignals()
(6199) TestExceptionHandler()
(6199) ***** Begin Exception Handling testing (C++) *****
(6199) ExceptionHandlingCpp::DivisionByZero()
(6199) Raising exception...
(6199) ExceptionHandlingCpp::HandleSignals(int, signinfo_t*, void*)
(6199) signal = SIGFPE
(6199) ExceptionHandlingCpp::CheckRecursiveExceptions()
(6199) Number of recursions so far = 1
(6199) Returning from exception handler...
(6199) ExceptionHandlingCpp::HandleSignals(int, signinfo_t*, void*)
(6199) signal = SIGFPE
(6199) ExceptionHandlingCpp::CheckRecursiveExceptions()
(6199) Number of recursions so far = 2
(6199) Returning from exception handler...
(6199) ExceptionHandlingCpp::HandleSignals(int, signinfo_t*, void*)
(6199) signal = SIGFPE
(6199) ExceptionHandlingCpp::CheckRecursiveExceptions()
(6199) Number of recursions so far = 3
(6199) Returning from exception handler...
(6199) ExceptionHandlingCpp::HandleSignals(int, signinfo_t*, void*)
(6199) signal = SIGFPE
(6199) ExceptionHandlingCpp::CheckRecursiveExceptions()
(6199) Number of recursions so far = 4
(6199) Returning from exception handler...
(6199) ExceptionHandlingCpp::HandleSignals(int, signinfo_t*, void*)
(6199) signal = SIGFPE
(6199) ExceptionHandlingCpp::CheckRecursiveExceptions()
(6199) Number of recursions so far = 5
(6199) Returning from exception handler...
(6199) ExceptionHandlingCpp::HandleSignals(int, signinfo_t*, void*)
(6199) signal = SIGFPE
(6199) ExceptionHandlingCpp::CheckRecursiveExceptions()
(6199) ExceptionHandlingCpp::UnregisterSignal(int)
(6199) Successfully reset SIGFPE's action to default!
(6199) Returning from exception handler...
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (6199) for package sample.experiments.androidexceptionhandling ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (6276) for package sample.experiments.androidexceptionhandling ----------------------------
(2 | 6276) MainApplication.onCreate()
(6276) JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM*, void*)
(6276) Initializing JavaVM...
(2 | 6276) MainActivity.onCreate(Bundle?)
(6276) Java_sample_experiments_androidexceptionhandling_KotlinExceptions_testExceptionHandlerFromCpp(JNIEnv *, jobject)
(6276) ExceptionHandlingCpp::RegisterSignals()
(6276) TestExceptionHandler()
(6276) ***** Begin Exception Handling testing (C++) *****
(6276) ExceptionHandlingCpp::DivisionByZero()
(6276) Raising exception...
(6276) ExceptionHandlingCpp::HandleSignals(int, signinfo_t*, void*)
(6276) signal = SIGFPE

The number in parenthesis is the main thread's ID. As shown in the above logs, an exception is raised, signal handler is invoked and keeps count of the iterations. By iterations, I'm referring to exception instruction -> signal handler -> exception instruction and so on. When 5 iterations are done, in the 6th time, UnregisterSignal is invoked to set the default handler, which should terminate the process. But what I've observed is, the process is somehow restarted. As shown in the above logs, the MainAcpplication class is invoked again with a different ID for the main thread.
When I stop registering for SIGFPE, then the process exits as expected. This is only happening for SIGFPE... when I repeat the same thing for SIGSEGV, it works as expected i.e., loops 5 times and when I set the default, process exits and doesn't restart.
Why does the process keep restarting for SIGFPE? I expect the process to quit after I set the default handler. Is this some Android studio setting? I've updated Android Studio, deleted and recreated the project multiple times, tried on different emulators, but nothing worked.
Environment:
Android studio version: Ladybug
Emulator OS: Android 13.0 (Tiramisu) and Android 14.0 (Upside down cake)
Update 1
I tested this in a real device (Android 13) and have more weird observations. SIGFPE never invokes the signal handler, and the flow just continues as if nothing has happened. As for SIGSEGV, it goes into the same loop which was observed in the emulators.
